# Need help making a wordpress loop that displays a catergory if its true,

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment I'm just thinking in terms of theory what I need to do, I'm editting another developers code so it can be slightly tricky.

I've created a new catergory called "home" and want the post I assign to this catergory to overwrite the current post that displays on the homepage. So if its selected it will appear on the homepage.

I've got 3 custom post types, and each one is gunna have a catergory called home.

Here is the code I've got at the moment that displays the latest post. Its unchanged and I just need abit of guidance on this.

```
<?php
$query               = new WP_Query('post_type=testimonial&showposts=1&paged=' . $paged);
$postcount           = 0; ?>

 <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $postcount++; ?>

<li> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-casestudy');
                                    }else { 
                                    ?>

<img src ="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<?php } ?></a>
<h4><a href  ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<p class     ="hm_text"><?php 
//the_excerpt(); 
echo get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'wpld_cf_home_page_text', true) ?></p>




</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: do I need to add catergory_name=home into the new WP_QUERY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **create your post category name = home**

```
 <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'category_name'=>'home',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'showposts' => '10',
        '&paged' => $paged,
    );
    $wp_query->query( $args );
    $postcount           = 0; 
?>

<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $postcount++; ?>
<li> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                the_post_thumbnail('thumb-casestudy');
        }else { 
    ?>
        <img src ="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
    <?php } ?>
        </a>
    <h4><a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Will this work ravi, I'm familiar with this but didn't know if it would work.

Comment: will it also return the other posts if there is know catergory found